# Как отфильтровать данные в dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview, filter

В dataGridView1 я записываю данные из db.sqlite с использованием SQLiteCommand и ExecuteReader.

впоследствии я создаю textbox в котором пишу:

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("title like '{0}%'", textBox2.Text);
    }
```

Но стоит начать что-то вводить как мне выдают ошибку: [image: Ошибка]

Я не понимаю в чем проблема и как с этим бороться. знаю, что обычно используют SqlDataAdapter, DataSet и Fill(), но вот у меня sqlite и надо фильтровать по нему.

HELP

Comment: тут же в ошибке написанно что у вас `dataGridView1.DataSource` равняется `null`

Comment: В нижней панели видно, что в `dataGridView1.DataSource` у вас `BindingSource`, а не `DataTable`. Поэтому применение `as` выдаёт `null`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Читаете данные из базы в dataTable
2. dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = //...
3. dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable

Comment: А каким образом из List<Films>считать? просто изначально я все в лист записывала а потом вот так заполняла:   
            _list = new List<Films>();
            bsUser.DataSource = _list;

            List<Films> list = SQLiteHelper.GetFilms();//получаем список из гетфилмс
            if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
            {
                _list.AddRange(list);
                bsUser.ResetBindings(false);
            }